# How can I enforce expiry day in SQL backup append?

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

If I make a database backup job, where I set Expire day = 2. Run this backup job once every day. How can I delete backup sets that are more than 2 days old? I'm Using SQL 2005 Express, so everything runs as script. This is the script running:

BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] TO  DISK = N'C:\Temp\DatabaseName.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 2, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO

After 5 days I have 5 backup set. This will fill up the disk....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do it with Express edition. It has no SQL Agent Job Scheduling Service shipped with it. Please see [table](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx) for comparison. You need to create batch script
to accommodate this or upgrade edition.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use some free tools for db backup that enable db backups expire  for custom dates? You just set it over the SQL Server Express and it runs scheduled backups with cleaning up old dated *.bak